# Datetime parse not working c#

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime

I am trying to read date from excel using code

```
String ss = (String)w.Cells[2 + i, 4].Value2;
dRow[3] = DateTime.Parse(ss);
```

Code works when `ss = "12/11/2015"` but gives error

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

when `ss = "13/11/2015"`

It gives error because month can not be 12 but it is taking date as month. This is what I think. Same code is working on other PC. Do I need to check my date time format or anything like date setting.

Comment: possible, because there is no 13th month in a year...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime.Parse` uses standard date and time format of your `CurrentCulture` settings *by default*.

Looks like your `CurrentCulture` has `MM/dd/yyyy` format as a short date format and since there is no month as `13` in Gregorian Calendar (which *probably* uses as a [`Calendar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.calendar.aspx) for your `CurrentCulture`), you get `FormatExcetion`.

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` method to specify your format exactly like;

```
dRow[3] = DateTime.ParseExact("13/11/2015", "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you get this as an input and you want to parse it to `DateTime`, you *have to* know which format it has. Other than that, it can generate ambiguous scenarios.

For example; what `01/02/2015` should be parsed as? 1st February or 2nd January?

You *shouldn't* assume that every string you supplied perfectly parsed with `DateTime.Parse` method. It is not *that* smart.